# When to use plain state over constructor(props)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that their are some similar questions like this, however im still confused on the following.

When to use state like this

```
Class Example extends Component {
  state = {
    name: ''
  }

 }
```

Over constructor props

```
Class Example extends Component{ 

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: ''
    }
  }
}
```

Does it have something to do with method binding ? because i can use onChange fine without binding it like this:

```
this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
```

I can still call onChange like

```
onChange = (e) => {

}

<Component onChange = {this.onChange} />
```

Comment: arrow functions auto bind. thats why you don't require binding.

Comment: so in a nutshell, i wouldn't need to use `this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)` because i have arrow functions that already bind it right ?

Comment: Right. Here is a great article: https://daveceddia.com/where-initialize-state-react/

Comment: ok thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in react new version you can initialise state directly without using this

```
constructor(Props){
super(props)
this.state ={
}
}
```

both of them are correct. you can use any of them.

i will choose first one because it is less code

and for any method you can directly use them like

```
  onChange = (e) => {

    }

<Component onChange = {this.onChange} />
```

there is no need to bind method in new versions of react

Answer (score 2):

The difference in your examples is purely syntactical, not functional. You can use both of them with the same effect.

Generally you assign a state in the constructor function when you want to compute the state based on some runtime logic (eg. based on the passed props). In that case you'll write it like that:

```
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      fullName: props.firstName + ' ' + props.lastName
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: let say if i wanted access to this.props - would i need the `constructor(props)super(props)` in this case ?

Comment: i guess my main question is, when would it be mandatory to use `constructor(props)super(props)`

Comment: React 'monkey patches' the props, so even if you didn't use a constructor you'll still have access to it... @randal